# the linear transformation with Rank(T) <n

Tags: linear-transformations

If $T:V\mapsto V$ is a linear transformation, such that $\operatorname{Rank}(T) < n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.
Prove that $\det(T)=0$.

Comment: I mean the actual question is If T:V->V is a linear transformation, such that Rank(T)<n , where n is the dimension of V.
Prove that determinant of T is zero.

Comment: Please help someone

Answer (score 0):

We can write the linear transformation, assuming $V$ is not infinite-dimensional, as an $n \times n$ matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional since you are talking about determinants. If this matrix has linearly independent rows, than Rank$(T)=n$. Thus if Rank$(T) < n$, then $A$ has linearly dependent rows, and thus $\det(A)=0$.

Next time, take some effort to state the question properly if you want people to take the effort to answer your question.